# Windows CMD rename files with numbers to add leading zeroes up to a certain field format length

Tags: windows, cmd, rename

I have files with filenames as ID numbers, and need to rename them to include leading zeroes on the ID number up to 7 digits long as well as add extra words to the file name, and keep the file extension.

It specifically needs to dynamically add leading zeroes only if it needs to, up to 7, as while most ID numbers are 6 digits and need 1 leading zero some are 5 or less digits long.

For example `123456` needs to be `0123456` and `123` needs to be `0000123`.

I'm using CMD as administrator and this simple command below worked fine previously (last year and a couple weeks ago) in adding leading zeroes to fit the format of the ID in question (7-digit number format), but now as of today it doesn't seem to be working. Now it is only renaming it to add "Report" to the file name.

```bash
Ren "C:\Users\folder\Reports\???????*.docx" "??????? Report.docx"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly in CMD, as per your question, you could try it like this, *(noting that I have replaced `C:\Users\folder` with `%UserProfile%`)*:

```bash
For /F "Delims=" %G In ('Dir "%UserProfile%\Reports\*.docx" /A:-D /B /O:N 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R "[0123456789][0123456789]*\.docx"') Do @If 1%~nG Lss 10000000 (Set "BaseName=1000000%~nG" & %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /V /D /C "Echo(Ren "%UserProfile%\Reports\%G" "!BaseName:~-7! Report%~xG"")
```

If you are satisfied with the output, remove `Echo(`, for example:.

```bash
For /F "Delims=" %G In ('Dir "%UserProfile%\Desktop\*.docx" /A:-D /B /O:N 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R "[0123456789][0123456789]*\.docx"') Do @If 1%~nG Lss 10000000 (Set "BaseName=1000000%~nG" & %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /V /D /C "Ren "%UserProfile%\Desktop\%G" "!BaseName:~-7! Report%~xG"")
```

Comment: All worked great! A lot less simple than the old command, but I'm just replacing file locations so it's not as bad and if that's the way it works now, then that's the way it works now. Thank you! (and thanks for editing my post to make it cleaner)